# Jlabel resizing java

Tags: java, jlabel, jtextpane

I was creating a JLabel inside the JTextPane with backGround Color and by the time I tried to resize it with the code `setSize , setPrefferedSize` and revalidate it both of them didnt work. I want all the width of Jlabel to to 130 and height of 20.

Is there another way to doing it?

Here is my code

```
final JLabel jl = new JLabel(rs2.getString("username"));
            final String username = rs2.getString("username");
            Border d = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1,10,1,10);
            Border d2 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
            Border d3 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(d2,d);
            jl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,20));
            jl.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,16));
            jl.setBorder(d3);


            jl.setOpaque(true);
            jl.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);


            Cursor c = new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
            jl.setCursor(c);
            jl.revalidate();
            jtp.insertComponent(jl);

            sd.insertString(sd.getLength(), "\n", SubPanel1.sas);
```

[image]

Comment: Try changing the `preferredSize` of the labels instead.

Comment: Thats what i did but it didnt work